# Drivers for now-unsupported laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

Damn you HP, this equipment is still perfectly usable otherwise!

I have an [HP Envy17 3070nr](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ENVY-17-3000-Notebook-PC-series/5145668/model/5218407).  HP dropped driver support after Windows 8, and Microsoft's aggressive push to Windows 10 has caused several pieces of software to stop working.  I am OK installing OEM drivers from the hardware manufacturers (ATI/AMD, Beats, etc) -- what is the process for finding these drivers?  I'm assuming an appropriately universal answer will be applicable to other makes / models as well.

For the example of the GPU driver, the normal AMD-supplied Catalyst Control Center installation will fail saying I need to use the laptop OEM drivers.  The laptop OEM driver will fail on an unsupported OS.  Windows 10 does install a generic driver, but misses key features like screen dimming or half the performance it's capable of.

Answer (score 0):

First step in this process is finding the specific make and model of controller for each feature under-the-hood. Common vendors (such as Intel) supply drivers for most components on the board. The best way to find this info is to find the spec sheet(s) for your machine.

However, the link you provided makes all that info fairly easy to find, already.

For example, from the support link for your machine, it appears Intel provides controllers for the core logic, ethernet, wifi, bluetooth, and HD audio. If you can get the specific model info, you could likely find the drivers on Intel's website (they are quite good for providing drivers, with their requisite installers). You'd likely even do well with an educated guess- chances are good many laptops from HP, in the same price range, shipped with the same controller chipsets. Chances are equally good that other vendors, who shipped models, around the same time, within the same price range, did also. Add to that, many vendors supply combined updaters, which would install one from a number of drivers, depending on which chipset they find in your machine.

Here's that driver page:
http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-ENVY-17-3000-Notebook-PC-series/5145668/model/5218407

Chipset-specific drivers may be available for, but aren't limited to:

- Core logic chipset
- Ethernet
- Wireless (usually combined with Bluetooth)
- USB
- GPU
- Audio
- Card reader
- SATA

Answer (score -1):

You should have linked specs rather than OEM support page (which 90% is always outdated software).

And assuming I'm not wrong, if you really have a Radeon 7690M + Intel gpu, I feel bad for you. 
That requires [very special drivers](http://leshcatlabs.net/forums/showthread.php?tid=6&page=13#pid16871) to work in Windows 10.

For the remainder, whatever W10 automatically download should be fine-ish.